# MonoTouch Custom UITableViewCell AccessoryView is Null

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, accessoryview

I created a custom UITableViewCell in a MonoTouch app I am building. Inside the cell I am succesfully setting:

```
Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
```

However when I attempt to change the background color of the AccessoryView my app crashes because AccessoryView is null:

```
AccessoryView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
```

As a matter of fact the only view within the cell that is not null is the ContentView.

Anyone has an idea why the AccessoryView is Null?

Answer (score 3):

`Accessory` and `AccessoryView` properties are related but do not change each others.

When you set your own **custom** view in `AccessoryView` then the value of `Accessory` will be ignored the the `UITableViewCell`.

> Anyone has an idea why the AccessoryView is Null?

Likewise if you set an `Accessory` then you do not get *access* to the *stock* view (thru the `AccessoryView` property) and events when supported, e.g. touch events for `DisclosureButton`, will be the cell (since you can't access the view).

If you want a custom looking accessory view then you can create one yourself and assign it to the `AccessoryView` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not want a custom looking accessory. My problem was that the accessory background color was not what I wanted and what I would expect it to be. My cell has a ContentView and I set its background color to white. I assumed I could do the same with the AccessoryView. I think since I can change the content view color I should be able to do the same with all the views on the cell. Anyway I solved my problem in a different way. Please read my answer below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

My original issue was that I was adding a an Accessory to the cell but the background of that accessory would not be the same as the background of the rest of the cell. It was getting the background of the underlying table view which was not what I wanted. When I tried to set the AccessoryView.Background color to what I wanted (thinking that that was culprit), the AccessoryView was null.

What I ended up doing to solve my issue was to create a new UIView with the background color I wanted and set that as my cells BackgroundView (since that was also null initially). This fixed my issue and my cell has the proper color everywhere.